# How can an application collecting data for a group of people send that data to their individual google fitness accounts?

Tags: google-fit, google-classroom

I have a few different applications for collecting fitness data from a group of people during group workouts.  I would like to send this data into each individuals google fitness account.  How would I go about getting authorization to send the data to all of their accounts?

I would also like to link this data to their google-classroom account.  Can this be done using the existing APIs?

Comment: What platform?  You can probably do it with the rest API's you will have to of get everyone to authorise your app.  I don't think you could do it with the Android API's they are too tied up to a single account on the device.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you have a one device that is being used by a teacher or coach to record data from multiple individuals. (For example, the number of pushups Alice, Bob and Charlie were able to do in 1 minute.)

Under this scenario, there's no good way to automatically send this data into individual accounts--each person would need to login on the teacher's device, and they'd probably need to do this every workout, which is a security and usability nightmare.

What you could do is store the workout data on your own server somewhere, and then, when Alice signs in on her device, you check with your server to see if there's relevant fitness data to import. If there is, then ask Alice whether she wants to import her data into Fit. (Or, equivalently, email her a link to her data for importing.)

(If Alice, Bob and Charlie bring their device to the workout, and can start an app before working out, then you can insert Fit data automatically. You might even be able to use the [Nearby APIs](https://developers.google.com/nearby/?hl=en) to set up the "group".)